# Can we send desktop push notification to specific user after login?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, laravel-5, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have just created desktop push notification for Chrome and Firefox using GCM (OneSignal). It works perfectly fine. Now I want to send push notification to specific users after login. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getUserId](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/website-sdk-api#getUserId) from the OneSignal SDK to get the OneSignal player / user id for the browse and send it to your server. You can then use `include_player_ids` on the OneSignal [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API call to send a notification to the specific user.